# Passing unique ptr to an async method

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++14, c++17, unique-ptr

I'm trying to call `reset()` on a vector of `unique_ptr`s asynchronously:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>> myVector;
for (auto& keyVal : myVector) {
  future<void> f = async(launch::async, [=]() {
    keyVal.second.reset();
  });
  listOfFutures.push_back();
}
```

This does not work for 2 reasons:

- The `reset()` function of `unique_ptr` is not marked `const`, but `unique_ptr` when copied by default gets `const`.
- If I mark the `async` function as `mutable`, the compiler tells me I'm calling an implicitly deleted copy constructor, which I do not understand.

Comment: If you managed to create a non-const ref to that unique_ptr, it wouldn't be a unique ptr anymore - you'd have two references to it. Defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yes that was my thinking as well, but there has to be a cleaner way to call reset on unique ptrs asynchronously, without removing them from original structure.

Comment: @sublime No because then it would no longer be a unique pointer, you would have two ways to control the lifetime of the object. If you want that use an `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: What's your goal with this btw? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Can't you just capture an iterator to the unique_ptr? Why are you doing this though?

Comment: @Mat this happens when my task is shutting down, in one of the function my destructor calls it's clearing all the threads that SomeClass holds. 
Closing these threads can take a while (ongoing processes) so I want to do it in parallel.

Comment: @sparik not exactly sure what you mean, but maybe add it in the answer format so it's more clear?

Comment: And what is the reason that you don't want to use the `move` solution? You reset the `unique_ptr` in the lamda, so that indicates that you won't use it outside of it anymore.

Comment: Would a parallel algorithm be ok for you? Such as `std::for_each(std::par, myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](auto& p){ p.second.reset(); });`?

Comment: @DanielLangr apologies, I meant myVector, updated the question.

Comment: @DanielLangr if I'm not mistaken, the parallel algorithm does exactly what is suggested in the answer below right?

Comment: @t.niese thats a fair comment, I think move may not be a bad idea considering all the other alternatives.

Comment: @sublime the point is that you want to release the `unique_ptr` only by the _"context"_ that owns it. But if you release it in the lamda of `async` then you imply that this thread is now owning the `unique_ptr` if so you should move it into that lambda. If you need the `unique_ptr` after the async task, then you need to ensure that the `myVector` still lives after all async is finished, so you would need to wait for the `future` to be resolved. And then the question is why not do `std::future<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>> = …` which would make the ownership more clear.

Comment: @sublime No, it does not. In the suggested answer, the number of created thread is equal to _the number of vector elements_, which is prone to _oversubscription_. Parallel `for_each` will likely create just up to as many threads as many cores are available, which makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want.

```
for (auto& keyVal : myMap) {
    future<void> f = async(launch::async, [&ptr = keyVal.second] () mutable {
      ptr.reset();
    });
    listOfFutures.push_back();
}
```

However, it is a bad idea as the data that the unique_ptr points at could be deleted at any time. Thus you should just use your version with std::move.

EDIT: stated that this is a bad idea as pointed out in the comments

Comment: Making something compile doesn't necessarily make something work. This is pretty much a boobytrap waiting to spring.

Comment: true this is a bad idea. But I think it answers the question that was ask.

Comment: If you are going to provide this answer you should at least provide warnings as to the fact this completely destroys the point of an `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Be very clear about the downsides in this answer. As an old friend of mine once said, "Don't leave code like that lying around. Some kid could find it."

Comment: care to elaborate more on why this is a bad idea compared to std::move?

Comment: @sublime because it runs at about the same speed (moving a unique_ptr is cheap) and you can't access the unique_ptr in myMap anyway as it could be reset at any time in a non-threadsafe non-atomic way.